# Need to pass long value to a variable to WLST, which expects L at end

Tags: python, shell, wlst

we are trying to pass long value to the WLDFAccessRuntime (mbean of weblogic), attribute is EarliestAvailableTimestamp & LatestAvailableTimestamp, which expects 'L' at the end.

EarliestAvailableTimestamp (Default Value)
cmo.getEarliestAvailableTimestamp()
1509097885002L

But we are trying to change the value via wlst script
a=1234
b=long(a) -- this value is passed to EarliestAvailableTimestamp()

Though its a long, but its not giving L at the end, so EarliestAvailableTimestamp() is not accepting the value.

Eg:

s=1519056698455
e=1519057598000

script value:
cursorname = cmo.openCursor(long(s),long(e),"")
print cursorname
CUSTOM/com.bea.wli.monitoring.sla.alertIterator-25--9159200561733388375

Maually Entered value:
cursorname = cmo.openCursor(1519056698455L,1519057598000L,"")
print cursorname
CUSTOM/com.bea.wli.monitoring.sla.alertIterator-26-6422683192499293139

Both the cursorname value should be same.

Comment: try `cursorname = cmo.openCursor(java.lang.Long(s),java.lang.Long(e),"") `

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin no luck, actually we are getting the variables (s & e), from shell script o/p, so python is taking it as string, though it changes to long after casting, but wlst is not accepting it, as it doesnt have L on the trail.

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been resolved, wlst was bypassing the python libraries, which caused the issue.

imported libraries with namespace fixed the issue.